# LWC setCustomValidity

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-textarea

In my custom page i have multiple multiple row, contains **lightning-input**, **lightning-combobox** and **lightning-textarea** it has horizontal scroll.

Each field has its own validation logic. My question here is Iam writing one method in Js file if any field has the `setCustomValidity .value = true` then i need to highlight the entire row in red color

Trying the below approach saying if any **lightning-textarea** field has `setCustomValidity !=null` then i can get the element  highlight the entire row in red color.

But this is not working for me can anyone help me on this.

```
handletesting() {
    let textAreaElement = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-textarea');
    textAreaElement.forEach(element => {
      console.log('element ' + element.setCustomValidity);
      console.log('element ' + element.reportValidity.value);
      console.log('element ' + element.checkValidity);
    });
  }
```

this is how iam setting the validation required message

```
 element.setCustomValidity("Value is required");
 element.reportValidity();
```

Please let me know if any additional details required.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation#:%7E:text=lightning%2Dinput%3E%0A%3C/template%3E-,Input%20Validation,-Client%2Dside%20input) which contains a section on validity

> To check the validity states of an input, **use the validity attribute**,
> which is based on the Constraint Validation API. To determine if a
> field is valid, you can access the validity states in JavaScript.
>
> ...
>
> This validity attribute returns an object with the following read-only
> boolean properties.
>
> badInput: Indicates that the value is invalid for any input type.
>
> **customError**: Indicates that a custom error has been set. See Custom
> Validity Error Messages.
> ...
>
> **valid**: True if none of the
> preceding properties are true.

You'll want to interact with the validity attribute

```javascript
let textAreaElement = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-textarea');
textAreaElement.forEach(element => {
    //should return false
    console.log('element ' + element.validity.valid);
    //should return true
    console.log('element ' + element.validity.customError);

});
```